# How do I condition a HAVING query?

Tags: sql, having

I have the following query:

```
select ctc.sentencia ,count(lg.id_libro) as cantidad
from cat_tipo_sentencia as ctc
left join libro_gobierno as lg on lg.cod_tiposentencia = ctc.id_sentencia
left join expedientes as e on e.id_expedientes = lg.cod_expediente
GROUP BY ctc.sentencia
```

I want to count the records that are in "libro_gobierno" of "cat_tipo_sentencia", but when conditioned it does not show me those that have 0 records and when removing the condition if it shows them, how could I condition so that the results return those that do not have records?

-
this is the conditioned query

```
select ctc.sentencia ,count(lg.id_libro) as cantidad
from cat_tipo_sentencia as ctc
left join libro_gobierno as lg on lg.cod_tiposentencia = ctc.id_sentencia
left join expedientes as e on e.id_expedientes = lg.cod_expediente
where e.cod_distrito= 130 
and e.cod_estado_pro=13
and ctc.id_sentencia in (1,8,10)
GROUP BY ctc.sentencia
```

and when trying to use "HAVING" I get an error since the conditions are not within the group

these are the data that throws me

```
sentencia1     1
```

but in my condition there are also other options but it does not show them to me because there are no records, and I would like it to return me similar to:

```
sentencia1     1
sentencia2     0
sentencia3     0
```

PD: Sorry for the English, I'm using translator :(

Comment: Move the conditions: `e.cod_distrito= 130 and e.cod_estado_pro=13` to the ON clause

Comment: Since my answer below did not give the results you expected, you should [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/60553112/edit) your question and add sample data (as DDL/DML statements), the results you are getting, and the results that you want.

Comment: Consider posting this question on the appropriate stack overflow site where you don't need to translate. Your question may be a good example of what they say "lost in the translation".

Answer (score -1):

In a `LEFT OUTER JOIN`, if you filter the outer table in the `WHERE` clause, the results become the same as if you did an `INNER` join. Rows from the main table that don't have a match in the joined table are filtered off.

You can avoid this by filtering in the `ON` clause of your join, instead of in the `WHERE` clause.

```
SELECT 
   ctc.sentencia
    ,count(lg.id_libro) AS cantidad
FROM 
  cat_tipo_sentencia AS ctc
LEFT JOIN 
  libro_gobierno AS lg 
    ON lg.cod_tiposentencia = ctc.id_sentencia
LEFT JOIN 
  expedientes AS e 
    ON e.id_expedientes = lg.cod_expediente
    AND e.cod_distrito = 130
      AND e.cod_estado_pro = 13
WHERE 
  ctc.id_sentencia IN (1,8,10)
GROUP BY 
  ctc.sentencia
```

I tried to use common words. I hope this translates OK for you!

Comment: executing it does not give me the expected results, I only have a record that gives me "id_sentencia" similar to:

`sentencia1   1`


but I would also like the other records in my catalog even if they are in "0", similar to

`sentencia1    1
sentencia2    0
sentencia3    0`